# I can't get content from simplexml

Tags: php, xml

I'm beginning to use simplexml and I don't know what I'm doing wrong .. :(

I want to extract a xml from a url, I'm using the following code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents($url));
```

And... print_r shows other object SimpleXML inside my array...It is correct? How can I read it?

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [action] => QUERY
    [response] => SUCCESS
    [responsedata] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

Thanks a lot,

Comment: did you try http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php ?

Comment: First of all put echo "<pre>"; before your print_r so that you can see exact array format in a better way. and put it here.

Comment: As floww said, Use simplexml_load_file instead!

Comment: Yes, I try simplexml_load_file, and I get the same result: `SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [action] => QUERY
    [response] => SUCCESS
    [responsedata] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)`

Answer (score 0):

[SimpleXMLElement::__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) provides an optional (3rd) argument called `data_is_url` for cases like yours.

> By default, data_is_url is FALSE. Use TRUE to specify that data is a path or URL to an XML document instead of string data.

You should try something like:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($url, 0, true);
```

Comment: I get the same result: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [action] => QUERY
    [response] => SUCCESS
    [responsedata] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)

Comment: Can you provide the URL or the XML that results when accessing it via browser?